# How to connect to Oracle with a password that includes semicolon

Tags: excel, vba, oracle, odbc, database-connection

I am using VBA to connect to an Oracle database. Everything is working fine unless the password contains a semicolon.

This is how I connect to the database:

```
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim strCon As String

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

strCon = "Driver={Oracle in OracleClient32_home1};Dbq=" & tnsName & ";" & _
          "Uid=" & user & "; Pwd=" & password & ";"

'Open the connection
cn.Open strCon
```

If the password is something like "`pass;word`", then the log-in fails saying that the password is wrong.

I tried:

- Enclosing the password in curly braces:

  ```
  Pwd={" & password & "};"
  ```

  This returned invalid string or buffer length as an error.
- Enclosing with double quotes:

  ```
  Pwd=" & Chr(34) & password & Chr(34) & ";"
  ```

  This also returened invalid string or buffer length as an error.

Comment: Try padding it with single quote `Pwd='" & password & "';"`

Comment: Thank you for your answer - unfortunately I also got the error 'invalid string or buffer length' as an error...

Comment: As a side node, I think the error with the invalid string or buffer length is a bit weird - could it be an 32bit - 64bit issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
strCon = "Driver={Oracle in OracleClient32_home1};Dbq=" & tnsName
cn.Open strCon, user, password
```

Or use the [OdbcConnectionStringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.odbc.odbcconnectionstringbuilder?view=netframework-4.8) (syntax could be wrong)

```
Dim strCon As New OdbcConnectionStringBuilder
strCon.Driver = "Oracle in OracleClient32_home1"

strCon.Add("Dbq", tnsName)
strCon.Add("Uid", user)
strCon.Add("Pwd", password)

cn.Open strCon.ToString()
```

[DbConnectionStringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbconnectionstringbuilder?view=netframework-4.8) might be another option

Comment: Thanks for your help! The first suggestion did unfortunately not work as I received the response that the password was wrong. For the second suggestion: VBA does not need to know the object for this - do you know the name of the reference that needs to be included?

Comment: `OdbcConnectionStringBuilder` is a .NET class, so could be difficult to use it in VBA. However when you get response "wrong password" then the connection string should work in general.

Comment: In general yes, but unfortunately this method also seems to have problems with a semicolon in the password :/